# What does this line means in Java

Tags: java

```
if (number < 0) number = (number* -1);
```

What does this line mean, especially `number*`, I've never seen before a statement like this in java, I'm new.

Comment: It's just poorly formatted multiplication.

Comment: If number is lesser than zero multiplies it for -1. It is a sort of absolute value of that number.

Comment: what do you think it means? why not just run it and see for yourself? basically, you are checking if a number is positive or negative, if it is negative, you turn it into the absolute value of the number (number * -1, with * being multiplication)

Comment: `*` just means times

Comment: Note: this would be simpler/faster as `number = Math.abs(number);`

Answer (score 9):

It looks a bit like a C pointer, but it’s just multiplication.

When properly formatted:

```
if (number < 0)
    number = number * -1;
```

This code multiplies `number` by `-1` if `number` is negative.

The code guarantees `number` is positive, **except if `number` is `Integer.MIN_VALUE`**, in which case it stays unchanged!

Also, best practice uses braces around the `if` block:

```
if (number < 0) {
    number = number * -1;
}
```

Comment: @xtra I believe *formatting* is restricted to the use of whitespace (including newlines), while *style* is much broader but includes formatting. CheckStyle rules for example include aspects of formatting like requiring spaces either side of operators, which is highly relevant to this question.

Answer (score 3):

If the number is less than 0, multiply it by -1 (negate it) or make it positive.  Same as absolute value.